# How to deal when the solid waste are stick on the toilet surface?

Tags: bathroom

I am using a shared toilet and we agree to close the cover when flushing the water after pooping. However, I recognize that my solid waste sometimes stick on the toilet wall and it is not a nice thing for the next person using the toilet.
I am wondering if there is any solution for it?

I know we can lift up the toilet cover after pushing the water but it may reduce the advantage of lifting down the toilet cover that the solid waste molecular can fly around the restroom.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you mean the waste is on the toilet seat?

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 it is inside the toilet but on the wall of the toilet, sorry for my confused explaination

Comment: So why not toilet brush, there's usually one anywhere here, even in public toilets, which the janitors are using. Most people don't clean even if leaving a mess, but some do. If you mean in cases when there's no brush available then it's a solid question ( ;-) ) but better mention it.

Comment: Why is this question even a thing? Are there genuinely people out there that do not know toilet brushes exist?

Comment: think the OP is talking about _toilet plume_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many agree that closing the cover before flushing the toilet is a "Good Thing™" to do.
Then, there are two different ways for clean-up.

- Wipe the solid matter from the surface manually with toilet tissue (wasteful of tissue) or fabric (wasteful of laundry materials of the soiled fabric).
  Discard the tissue/launder the fabric.
   or
- Use a toilet brush when there is one available. After using it, rinse the brush clean.

Then, (either way) wash your hands.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Flush the toilet BEFORE you use it.  That way the toilet bowl is wet and it's harder for anything to stick to it.

(Flush it afterwards too :) )

Comment: @what a great comment

Comment: Practical (+1) but very wasteful (-1).

Answer (score 2):

Nobody really enjoys cleaning a toilet, but there's actually no way to avoid it. What has to be done, must be done. So, a toilet brush is a must. It really helps if you keep it as clean as possible. Pour a few drops of WC cleaning detergent (heavy duty laundry detergent works well, too) into a toilet brush holder (with a little water added). It cleans the brush in the meantime and maintains a fresh odour. Every time you do no. 2, flush and check if there's anything "left". Spray or sprinkle lightly with a toilet cleaning detergent (cleaner), then use the brush. Flush again. Replace the liquid in the toilet brush holder every couple of days (at least once a week) - water + a few drops of detergent! And don't forget the lime-scale build-up. Once a week a little of elbow grease goes a long way. Put on rubber gloves, rub with detergent (WC heavy duty cleaner or lime scale dissolvent) flush once or twice, then wipe all surfaces above the water lever dry with a paper towel or a machine washable cleaning cloth. Most important: repeat regularly.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same thing. I’m assuming the solid waste is on the ceramic bucket. Just use a pipe, close the pipe in half using your thumb, so that the force is high, and point it to the solid waste. It will go to the water. Then flush again.